# Entity Framework Connection strings issue

Tags: entity-framework, dll, entity-framework-4, connection-string

im developing a class library (dll) with visual studio 2012, this library contains a model first created database, with the connection string setted on its app.config file.

Now, im creating a console app (actually a test, but for this its pretty much the same) with an added reference to the dll project. 
At first i thought the console app didnt need to know anything about the database, since it was using the dll, however i got a connection string missing error. Fine i added it and it worked, but this isn't what i want, i need the dll to encapsulate all the database related stuff.
Also, what bothers me the most, is that the connection string is also needed on BOTH the dll and the app, even the .mdf file(im using local sql server) generated in the dll/bin/debug folder is needed and copied over to the app/bin/debug folder so i need the file to be on both sides...

How can i make the dll to work by itself, using its own config file and not the app config file? And no, using some kind of service is not an option, it needs to be a dll!

Answer (score 0):

in your database class you can add your connection string like this as base parameter

```
public class mydb:DbContext
{
   public mydb() :base("Server=....")
    {
    }
}
```

or you can add your Connection string to app.config and just put its name in base

Example:

```
 public mydb() :base("ConnectionstringName")
```

Comment: The second one doesn't fix the issue, since that's what it already does. The problem is that the app is looking for the connection string in its app.config rather than the .dll config.

Comment: Can you explain how do i put this string into the first way so it works? 

<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Contexto" connectionString="metadata=res://*/OL4RENTDB.csdl|res://*/OL4RENTDB.ssdl|res://*/OL4RENTDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\OL4RENTDB2.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>